# DoubleValueSerializer and DoubleSerializer

Tags: apache-flink

`DoubleSerializer` and `DoubleValueSerializer` are all implemented `TypeSerializerSingleton` interface, they shared same methods, and in `DoubleValue`,  the document shows that, it is a boxed value of java `Double`.

My question is, since we have `DoubleValueSerializer`, why we still need `DoubleSerializer`, what is the design in here?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Also, why DoubleSerializer is immutable, but DoubleValueSerializer is not?

Answer (score 1):

The `DoubleSerializer` and `DoubleValueSerializer` exist because the former serializes java `Doubles` and the latter serializes `DoubleValue` instances. These types are different.

The `DoubleValue` type represents a java `Double` which implements the `Key` and `Value` interface. These interfaces date back to the time when Flink could not directly handle java primitives. There you always had to wrap them in a `Value` type. Nowadays, there is no necessity anymore to use them directly. However, they are still used internally for some components.